# We can open JMeter through jmeter.bat and ApacheJMeter.jar. What's the difference?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

We can open JMeter through `jmeter.bat` and `ApacheJMeter.jar`.

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `jmeter.bat` is batch file for windows only which open command line
   prompt

   It execute `ApacheJMeter.jar` internally but add more logic as checking minimum java version (1.8 for version 3.2) or adding parameters as set `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`
2. `ApacheJMeter.jar` is a jar that can be executed **also** in linux
   without command line prompt

See also [other](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) options to run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

ApacheJMeter.jar file is an executable jar so it can be run by either clicking on it in windows/linux if it is associated to java application.

jmeter.sh/jmeter.bat is a shell file that ensure correct options are setup like memory heap, jvm options , java minimum version.

It is advised to use the second option after potentially adapting heap size to your test requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.