# difference between jmeter.bat/jmeter.sh And jmeter.file

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, heap-memory

I would need clarification on jmeter.bat/sh and jmeter.FIle which are in bin folder.

With example:

1.If i setup different HEAP size in **jmeter** and **jmeter.bat/sh** file,which one will be considered.?

2.Does the above depend on how i run the test?(for ex: **jmeter** -n -t or **jmeter.bat/sh** -n -t)

3.If the test started with **jmeter** command instead of **jmeter.bat** ,will intern jmeter.bat be called and hence heap in jmeter.bat be used or vice-versa?

Update1: Adding screenshot where we can see jmeter/jmeter.bat/jmeter.bat files
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update one file [based on your OS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) Windows/ Unix

> To run JMeter, run the jmeter.bat (for Windows) or jmeter (for Unix) file.

Both execute internally [ApacheJMeter.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671519/we-can-open-jmeter-through-jmeter-bat-and-apachejmeter-jar-whats-the-differenc)

In windows execute jmeter -n -t is actually calls jmeter.bat

In Unix you can call either jmeter or jmeter.sh

Comment: Thanks for your response. Im not confused between jmeter.sh and jmeter.bat.   But im confused between jmeter without any extension and jmeter.bat or jmeter.sh

Comment: @shey I didn't write .sh and jmeter and jmeter.sh both are for unix

Comment: which means in windows if i run the test with jmeter -n -t is this same as jmeter.bat -n -t
?

Comment: in the case of unix ,what will be the difference between running --jmeter -n -t and jmeter.sh -n -t ?

Comment: @shey in windows execute jmeter -n -t is actually calls jmeter.bat, about difference between .sh and not extension, please ask a new question

Comment: i have asked a new quiestion -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64696003/jmeterdifference-between-jmeter-sh-and-jmeter-without-extension-file-in-jmeter      please can you check

Answer (score 0):

Looking into your screenshot it seems that you're running Windows so the only file you should be considering is [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.bat)

If you want to change JVM Heap it's better to go for changing [`HEAP` environment variables](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.bat#L46) on Windows level like:

```
set HEAP=4G && jmeter.bat
```

when you type `jmeter` Windows is looking for a relevant executable or shell script first in the current folder than on [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) so `jmeter` will call `jmeter.bat` if you're invoking it from JMeter's "bin" folder, if you do it from another folder the command-line interpreter will look for it in PATH and if nothing will be found - it'll fail with "'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)