# Jmeter:Difference between jmeter.sh and jmeter without extension file in jmeter

Tags: linux, jmeter, performance-testing, heap-memory

I would need clarification on jmeter.sh and jmeter file without ext ,which are in bin folder.

With example:

1.If i setup different HEAP size in jmeter and jmeter.sh file,which one will be considered.?

2.Does the above depend on how i run the test?(for ex: jmeter -n -t or jmeter.sh -n -t)

3.If the test started with jmeter command instead of jmeter.sh ,will intern jmeter.sh be called and hence heap in jmeter.sh be used or vice-versa?

related question to the difference b/w jmeter.bat and jmeter-
[difference between jmeter.bat/jmeter.sh And jmeter.file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695466/difference-between-jmeter-bat-jmeter-sh-and-jmeter-file)

Answer (score 2):

- [jmeter.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter.sh) is a **wrapper** for `jmeter` script (without extension) which does some pre-requisite validations like getting current working dir, getting Java version, constructing arguments depending on Java version, etc. so you'd better use **this file** for running JMeter under Unix and derivatives
- [jmeter](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter) is a wrapper for ApacheJMeter.jar binary, it sets default JVM arguments and overrides and adds more Java arguments depending on your operating system

The sequence is the following:

- `jmeter.sh` calls `jmeter`
- `jmeter` calls `ApacheJMeter.jar`

If you want to change HEAP or whatever - set the appropriate environment variable like:

```
HEAP=4G && export HEAP && ./jmeter.sh -n -t /path/to/test.jmx ...
```

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Answer (score 0):

jmeter.sh calls jmeter, both unix [scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) , `jmeter` is the main/default script

> jmeter
> run JMeter (in GUI mode by default). Defines some JVM settings which may not work for all JVMs.

> jmeter.sh
> very basic JMeter script (You may need to adapt JVM options like memory settings).

You can set before running both the [JVM_ARGS](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html)

> It may be necessary to set a few environment variables to configure the JVM used by JMeter. Those variables can be either set directly in the shell starting the jmeter script. For example setting the variable JVM_ARGS will override most pre-defined settings, for example

> ```
> JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" jmeter -t test.jmx [etc.]
> ```

> will override the HEAP settings in the script.